# Recent LDAP user list missing in greeter using lightdm

Tags: users, login, ldap, lightdm

I am switching our desktop manager from xfce to mate on centos 7.4.

This means that we are switching from gdm to lightdm.

For some reasons, it is impossible for our recent user authenticated via a freeipa to appear in the recent user lists, which means that our users needs to enter all their login infos each time they log in.

I have looked long and hard, and it does not seem to be a setting issues. I have tried to activate and deactivate all the relevant settings regarding sessions, with no luck.

For what i have been able to glean, a file need to be created in `/var/lib/AccountsService` for our users to appear in that list, but is not. Yet, this folder is still being read at lightdm startup. It reads org.freedesktop.Accounts which seem to be used to create this list.

Under GDM, that file is correctly created when a ldap user logs out.

User locally created do not experience this issue, and are directly present both in the user list and in `/var/lib/AccountsService`.

If anyone could nudge me in the right direction. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried to change `minimum-uid` in the users.conf and `greeter-show-remote-login` in the Seat section of the lightdm config.

Comment: Yes, i tried both of these things and it does not seem to change anything.

Comment: The reason may be the UID of your LDAP user so AccountsService thinks it is a system user and does not cache it. What is the output when you send a dbus query: `dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Accounts /org/freedesktop/Accounts org.freedesktop.Accounts.ListCachedUsers`

Comment: The result correctly list the account i manually added to Accountsservice and the local user of the machine :

 method return time=1650974952.406261 sender=:1.15 -> destination=:1.34115 serial=243 reply_serial=2
   array [
      object path "/org/freedesktop/Accounts/User784060400"
      object path "/org/freedesktop/Accounts/User8080"
   ]

Also, i have noticed that org.freedesktop scans what is in /var/lib/AccountsServices.

Under GDM, files are generated there once the user logs out.
Is there a way to interract with cached users?

Comment: with `dbus-send --system --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Accounts /org/freedesktop/Accounts org.freedesktop.Accounts.CacheUser string:"<ldap_username>"` command a user can be manually cached. I still think that the problem might be related to the UID of the user. You may also have a look at /etc/login.defs for `UID_MAX` and `UID_MIN` settings.

Comment: Your last command correctly cache our users. 

Though i had already reviewed /etc/login.defs,  everythings seem to be in order there. Our UID's are well withing there min & max values.

Though, maybe lightdm consider that our ldap users are system users none the less?

Comment: I have created a test user on our freeipa with a UID in the same range as the local user's and the problem is the same.
It seems that lightdm is not generating cache for ldap users as GDM does.